# unexpected end of stream

Tags: android, soap

Estou consumindo um webservice no android. 
Mas estou com problemas no seguinte método:

```
 public static SoapObject Retornar_Lista_UFs(int pCodigo_Entidade) {

    Financeiro_NG oFinanceiro = new Financeiro_NG();

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(oFinanceiro.WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, oFinanceiro.OPERATION_NAME_UF);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("pCodigo_Entidade");
    pi.setValue(pCodigo_Entidade);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(oFinanceiro.SOAP_ADDRESS);

    SoapObject response = null;
    try {
        httpTransport.call(oFinanceiro.SOAP_ACTION_UF, envelope);
        response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.d("Erro", exception.toString());
    }
    return response;

}
```

É um simples método para buscar a lista de UF na base de dados. 
Mas ao chamar esse método no android dá o erro `unexpected end of stream`;
No debug até mostra a lista lá, e não sei o que significa esse erro. Passei horas procurando uma solução.

Se mudar o `envelope.bodyIn` para `envelope.getResponse()` o erro continua.

EDIT:

Consegui contornar o problema adicionando mais um catch:

```
     catch (ProtocolException exception)
    {
        response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    }
```

Assim ele retorna a lista se houver o erro descrito, o que claramente não é o certo a se fazer, mas ainda não consegui resolver o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]